# How to Assign A Structure Type In Declaration Moment?

Tags: vb.net, structure

I declared a variable whose type is structure i did , but i can't **assign it**

```
Structure SHAPE
    Dim x as integer
    Dim y as integer
End Structure

Dim Shape1 As SHAPE = (15, 20) ' << The Problem is here

Public Sub test()
    Label1.Text = Shape1.x
End Sub
```

Comment: [`System.Drawing.Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point) structure that can be used instead `Dim Shape1 = New Point(15, 20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures don't magically understand whatever way you choose you try to get data into them. Like any type, if you want to be able to create an instance with specific data then add a constructor to do that, e.g.

```vb
Public Structure Shape

    Public ReadOnly Property X As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Y As Integer

    Public Sub New(x As Integer, y As Integer)
        Me.X = x
        Me.Y = y
    End Sub

End Structure
```

You then create an instance of that type as you would any other:

```vb
Dim shape1 As New Shape(15, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either create a constructor and call the constructor. Or populate the properties after constructing.

Eg.

```
Dim Shape1 As SHAPE = New SHAPE With {.x = 1, .y = 2}
```

Equivalent to:

```
Dim Shape1 As SHAPE = New SHAPE()
Shape1.X = 1
Shape1.y = 2
```

Creating a constructor is the preferred way, because structs should in general be immutable. Doing so and setting the properties to readonly is an easy way to make a struct immutable:

```
Public Structure Shape

    Public ReadOnly Property X As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Y As Integer

    Public Sub New(x As Integer, y As Integer)
        Me.X = x
        Me.Y = y
    End Sub

End Structure
```

Comment: Just to emphasize the point that `Structure` instances should be immutable, you will get code that is very hard to reason about correctly if you try to mutate an instance of a `Structure` because of the language requirements to create copies of them in certain workflows.